# How to use versioning when using same .snk file for multiple SharePoint projects in the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, security, visual-studio-2012, solution

I am trying to find the right way to set up my SharePoint solution with miltiple projects (in VS2012). In that, I am having difficulty understanding the concept of reusing the strong name key file.

One particular thing that I cannot wrap my head around is using one .snk file for a company's solutions. But if you are doing that, wouldnt that mean the version information will also be shared among the projects that share the key file? Different SharePoint projects could have different versions. So, how does this setup work?

Some of the urls that I have refered to so far:

- [Using the same Strong Name Key (.snk) file for multiple projects:](http://csharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/using-the-same-strong-name-key-snk-file-for-multiple-projects/)
- [Sharing a Strong Name Key File Across Projects:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/04/24/582278.aspx#comments%20%28VS%202005%29)
- [The Secrets of Strong Naming:](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html)

Answer (score 2):

The key file only determines the PublicKeyToken part of the full assembly name. The version name remains specific to each project and can be set independently.

Comment: So, .snk is the part of strong name of an assembly? Then in VS, what components are part of strong name? So far I have, .snk file and AssemblyInfo.cs. And how does the private key come into play?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with private key and how would you like to use it for signing assemblies? What is it that you are trying to achieve?